# Schnorr's signature scheme with addition of modulus secure?

Tags: signature, schnorr-signature

In Schnorr signature scheme,
$s=(k-xe)$
$ s_1=(k-xe_1)$ 
If the same key $k$ is used, then it is possible to reveal $k$ and $x$ value by using $\frac{s-s_1}{e_1-e}$.
 
However, if we add $s=(k-xe) \bmod q$, $s_1=(k-xe_1) \bmod q$, $q$ is known by users.
 Will modulus usage prevent to reveal $k$ and $x$ value? If the modification scheme is secure, will there be more modification of Schnorr signature public key $g^x$ to something?

Comment: Please reformulate your question. As it is stated now, it does not make sense.

Comment: What shall "addition of modulus" mean? Also, the last sentence "Any changes to public parameters, for example, g^x mod q"  cannot be understood, because the verb is missing.

Comment: I am still not clear what is your intention. Do you want to construct two (or more) Schnorr signatures and always use the same secret k value?

Comment: @Cryptostasis..yes

Comment: An then you want to calculate the first signature $s$ as a usual SChnorr signature and the second signature differently, say as $s_2 = s+s_1$ ?

Comment: @ Cryptostasis.  Using first and second using usual Schnorr signature but now using modulus value  $s=(k-xe)\bmod q$ for both signatures.

Answer (score 2):

There's no chance to hide private key $x$ in case of re-using $k$ by calculating in the ring modulus $q$.
Formula $\frac{s - s_1}{e_1 - e}$ is well-defined over the ring modulo any prime $q$. In particular, extended Euclidean algorithm would do the division.